# ImportError: cannot import name 'entrenamiento'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm taking Python again after a long time.

I'm developing a little software to help me learn a new lengauge (japanese)

I tried to make a class and import it, but it did't work. Just for testing, I created a very simple class and when I tried to import it I got an error.

Here is the code (both files trainer.py and prueba.py are in the same folder):

file trainer.py

```
class trainer:
    def entrenamiento(t,dicc):
        print(t)
        print(dicc)
```

file prueba.py

```
from trainer import entrenamiento

entrenamiento(1,2)
```

When I run prueba.py I get the following:

```
C:\Users\nico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/japanese/prueba.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/japanese/prueba.py", line 1, in <module>
     from trainer import entrenamiento
 ImportError: cannot import name 'entrenamiento'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also tried with a different code in prueba.py:

```
import trainer

trainer.entrenamiento(1,2)
```

and I got this:

```
C:\Users\nico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe 
C:/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/japanese/prueba.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/japanese/prueba.py", line 3, in <module>
trainer.entrenamiento(1,2)
AttributeError: module 'trainer' has no attribute 'entrenamiento'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Finally, just for checking I tried the following

file trainer.py

```
class trainer:

    print('hello world')
```

file prueba.py

```
import trainer
```

and I got no error

```
C:\Users\nico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe 
C:/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/japanese/prueba.py
hello world

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm working with Python 3.6.5 and PyCharm 2018.1.4 Community Edition

Is there any mistake in my coding or maybe a configuration issue?

I thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm so, you made a little mistake with your import in `prueba.py`

it should be:

```
from trainer import trainer

trainer.entrenamiento(1,2)
```

where the first trainer points to `trainer.py`and the second points to the class.

you can now access the function defined inside the class using the syntax `class.function` eg. `trainer.entrenamiento(1,2)`

i would recommend to change either the name of `trainer.py` or the class `trainer` as it's obviously confusing.